# Is it possible to set up IBM data stage through Docker?

Tags: docker, datastage

I want to run IBM Infosphere DataStage locally. Can I set it up through Docker? Are there any alternatives, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. At least not at current version.